Can a fact-finder's decision, based on an inference from testimony, be appealed?
Suppose in a bench trial, a witness testifies that she does indeed "own blue pants." Later in the testimony she mentions that all her blue pants have been in storage since the 1970s.
In the judge's decision, the judge finds that the witness owns blue pants and therefore was the woman on the video footage, etc. In other words, the case was decided based on the witness being the woman in blue pants even though she never testified to having worn such pants in years.
Was the judge allowed to draw such conclusions from testimony? Can his inference be appealed?

In analyzing these related questions, it may assist you to understand that you really can't appeal an inference, period. You can only appeal a judgment, and you need to identify a basis for reversing that judgment -- in your case, that would likely mean asking an appeals court to conclude that the judgment was not supported by sufficient evidence, or that it was against the manifest weight of the evidence, or something like that. Identifying the actual basis for your appeal would probably help you to understand exactly how far the judge can go with these inferences.

Thank for your guidance. I am looking for a civil case that was successfully appealed on the grounds that the judge's inferences were inappropriate and not directly supported by any evidence or testimony

Does this answer your question? Is a judge's completely arbitrary determination of credibilty subject to appeal? or Can you appeal a decision if the judge based it on subjective and unclear testimony? - This is exactly the same thing as your other 2 questions: You can not appeal  a finding of fact unless it is bonkers.

@Trish I asked this more specific question which addresses inferences and not credibility. It is one thing for the judge to assess credibility, it is another for the judge to say "I believe the witness meant X when she said Y"

The answer is still: The finder of fact is given utmost deference as long as there is any way to reach the conclusion with the evidence or testimony presented.

@Trish How could this not be bonkers? The witness said her blue pants were in storage at the time of the video, so she couldn't have been the woman in the footage. Is the judge justified in believing the testimony that she owns the pants, but doesn't find the part about them being in storage credible? Should he at least explain why he discredited that part of the testimony?

@Barmar - Sure.  Judges (like juries) are free to believe some parts of a witness's testimony and disbelieve other parts.  The judge (and/ or jury) is free to decide that the woman's testimony that she owns blue pants is truthful, the testimony that all her blue pants were in storage was false, and that the video evidence establishes that she was the woman wearing blue pants.

A judge's findings of fact can only be successfully appealed if the finding of fact has no support in the trial court record, including any reasonable inferences from the trial court record. If an appellate court feels that the inference was reasonable, then it will uphold the verdict.

And the appellate court has to hold the trial court under utmost deterrence wherever something has any reasonable foundation
